# ng-model not updating md-slider with md-discrete directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```css
.overflow-hidden{ 
  overflow: hidden;
}

md-slider:not(.active) .md-thumb-container{
      transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1)!important;    
}

md-slider:not(.active) .md-track-fill{
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1)!important; 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.1/angular-material.min.css">
  </head>
  <body layout="column">
    <div>
      <!-- overflow-hidden because the scrolling (known issue) -->
  <md-content class="md-padding overflow-hidden">
    <h3>Demo</h3>
    <div layout>
      <md-slider flex md-discrete step="1" min="1" max="25" aria-label="rating" ng-model="value">
      </md-slider>
      
    </div>
    <p>Value = {{value}}</p>
    
  </md-content>
</div>
    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

while sliding `ng-model` value is not updating in `md-slider` when I am using `md-discrete` directive, without that its working fine. How I can able to get that work with `md-discrete` ?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? ng-model is updating in the above code.

Comment: @Vivz when sliding that ng-model is not updating, on drag end only its updating

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using `md-discrete` is to updated the `ng-model` only on the `drag end`, because sometimes we run a bulky function (time consuming!) and it will run for each change of the slider's `ng-model`, so by using `md-discrete`, the default functionality is to update after the drag-end. My suggestion is to use the `md-slider` without `md-discrete` if you don't want this behavior.

```js
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```css
.overflow-hidden{ 
  overflow: hidden;
}

md-slider:not(.active) .md-thumb-container{
      transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1)!important;    
}

md-slider:not(.active) .md-track-fill{
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1)!important; 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.1/angular-material.min.css">
  </head>
  <body layout="column">
    <div>
      <!-- overflow-hidden because the scrolling (known issue) -->
  <md-content class="md-padding overflow-hidden">
    <h3>Demo</h3>
    <div layout>
      <md-slider flex step="1" min="1" max="25" aria-label="rating" ng-model="value">
      </md-slider>
      
    </div>
    <p>Value = {{value}}</p>
    
  </md-content>
</div>
    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want that md-discrete also, which indicates current step value

Comment: @Durga Then you need to mod the insides of `angular-material` which is not a wise thing to do!